# RecyclerView Adapter in unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing

How to test support library classes when running unit tests in Android Studio?
According to the introduction on http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support it works with the default Android classes:

> Unit tests run on a local JVM on your development machine. Our gradle plugin will compile source code found in src/test/java and execute it using the usual Gradle testing mechanisms. At runtime, tests will be executed against a modified version of android.jar where all final modifiers have been stripped off. This lets you use popular mocking libraries, like Mockito.

However, when I try to use Mockito on a RecyclerView adapter like so:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    adapter = mock(MyAdapterAdapter.class);
    when(adapter.hasStableIds()).thenReturn(true);
}
```

Then I will receive the error message:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
3. the parent of the mocked class is not public.
   It is a limitation of the mock engine.
```

The reason is that the support library does not provide such a jar file "where all final modifiers have been stripped off".

How do you test it then? By subclassing & overriding the final methods perhaps (which doesn't work so, NO). Perhaps PowerMock?

Comment: Check out my tests: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/AndroidGradleTemplate/blob/master/Example-AllLibraries/src/test/java/burrows/apps/example/template/adapter/BaseAdapterTest.java

Comment: @JaredBurrows I saw you deleted this test in commit 7ebf6a36911cc on Aug 28, 2016. Was there a problem with the test?

Comment: Do you have a link to the commit?

Comment: @JaredBurrows: sure: https://github.com/jaredsburrows/android-gradle-java-app-template/commit/7ebf6a36911cc

Answer (score 2):

## PowerMockito Solution

Step 1:
Find the right Mockito & PowerMock version from https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockitoUsage13, add it to build.gradle:

```
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.8"
```

*Update them only together and in accordance to the usage page.*

Step 2: 
Setup up the unit test class, prepare the target class (containing the final methods):

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest( { MyAdapterAdapter.class })
public class AdapterTrackerTest {
```

Step 3:
Replace Mockito... methods with PowerMockito:

```
adapter = PowerMockito.mock(PhotosHomeAlbumsAdapter.class);
PowerMockito.when(adapter.hasStableIds()).thenReturn(true);
```

Comment: Why use `PowerMockito` vs `Mockito`?

Comment: Mostly because `hasStableIds()` is declared `final`.

Comment: Mockito supports mocking finals since 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    adapter = mock(MyAdapterAdapter.class);
    when(adapter.hasStableIds()).thenReturn(true);
}
```

The compiler is not interpretating "when" key. You might use "Mockito.when" (in Java) or Mockito.`when`(in kotlin). Those apostrophes are needed due the key "when" its already existent in Kotlin language. You might use whenever instead Mockito.`when` though.